# undefined function wp_redirect() in custom file

Tags: wordpress, redirect, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-plugin-creation

I'm trying to redirect user to search page having customized query. I'm stuck with wp_redirect() and getting error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_redirect()
```

Here is my redirection code:

**customFile.php**

```
<?php /* Template Name: customFile*/ ?>
<?php
    // Logic to build $cSearch
    //  $cSearch is generated above in this file
    $baseUrl = site_url().'/?s='. $cSearch;
    wp_redirect( $baseUrl, 302 );
    exit();
```

This file is required once in main plugin file.

Answer (score 0):

I guessing that you  try to use `wp_redirect` before the function included by wordpress.

Try this:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', function() {
    $baseUrl = site_url().'/?s='. $cSearch;
    wp_redirect( $baseUrl, 302 );
    exit();
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code

```
<?php /* Template Name: customFile*/ ?>
<?PHP
if (!defined('ABSPATH')) {
  require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php');
}
// Logic to build $cSearch
//  $cSearch is generated above in this file
$baseUrl = site_url().'/?s='. $cSearch;
wp_redirect( $baseUrl, 302 );
exit();
```